# Importing data into an array, column by column

Tags: matrix, import, files-and-directories, list-manipulation

I'm building a large matrix having different sized rows consisting of a few columns. The different columns are imported .txt files.

Why can't I build the matrix column by column? For example, I thought I could populate the first column by evaluating

```
NumberConcentration [[All, 1]] = 
 Import["C:\\Users...NumberConcentration.txt", "Table"][[87]]
```

*Mathematica* gives me an error saying this part of the array does not exist.

> Set::partd: Part specification NumberConcentration[[All, 1]] is longer than depth of object. >>

Do I have to define intermediate values and then combine all of them to one matrix? Or is my syntax wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make your syntax work, you can define

```
NumberConcentration = ConstantArray[{},100];
```

Then use

```
NumberConcentration[[1]] = Import["C:\\Users...NumberConcentration.txt", "Table"][[87]]
```

where `100` should be replaced by the number of files you want to import. This should get rid of the error message. You don't need to have the `All` there.

Or, you can bypass this step by making a list of all the file names (here `files`) and then importing them all at once

```
files = {"file1.txt", "file2.txt"};
NumberConcentration = Import[#, "Table"][[87]] & /@ files
```

If you want to attach a path to all the files (as asked in the comments):

```
path = "C\\:this\\that\\";;
fullFiles = First[Outer[StringJoin, {path}, files]]

{"C:\this\that\file1.txt", "C:\this\that\file2.txt"}
```

which builds the list of full-path file names.

Comment: related to this: do you know if I can shorten the filepath string. For example, if my Mathematica script is in C:\ProgramFiles, and I want to refer to a file in a folder inside ProgramFiles folder, can I do that in mathematica with a shorter reference string than C:\ProgramFiles\Folder\File.txt. For example, Import["Folder\File"], or something like that

Comment: Say you have `path="C:\this\that\"`. Then a construct like `Table[Import[path<>files[[i]]],{i,1,Length[files]}]` should work. (`<>` is short for `StringJoin`.) You may have to "escape" the backslashes, i.e., use double backslashes.

Comment: @l3win consider adding this comment as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Referring to Your comment:

> For example, if my Mathematica script is in C:\ProgramFiles, and I want to refer to a file in a folder inside ProgramFiles folder, can I do that in mathematica with a shorter reference string than C:\ProgramFiles\Folder\File.txt [...] - l3win

**Automatization**

```
SetDirectory@NotebookDirectory[];
files = FileNames["*", {FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "FolderName"}]}];
```

**Importing 1**

Next, assuming You want to `Import` all files from `FolderName`, **bill s's way** is natural also to me. But, You have also said that those should be collumns. Assuming each has equal length we need to do transposition:

```
 NumberConcentration = Import[#, "Table"][[87]] & /@ files;
 NumberConcentration = Transpose@NumberConcentration;
```

**Importing 2**

But **Your way** is also possible. You only have to define earlier what `NumberConcentration` is. Column length - `100` can be set by import first file and checking `Length` of it.

```
NumberConcentration = ConstantArray[ ,{100, Length@files}];
Do[NumberConcentration[[;;, i]] = Import[files[[i]], "Table"][[87]], {i,Length@files}];
```

**Summary**

Big advantage is that You only need to type "FolderName" once, and no file names manually. If there are also other files in FolderName, and You only want to `Import` those of txt type, then simply `FileNames["*.txt", ...`

There might be some typos in code, I can not check if it is working now.

Comment: Heya Kuba, I +1ed. Just a quick note, expr[[;; , i]] is the same as expr[[All,i]], right? As the OP also used All.

Comment: Heya @JacobAkkerboom :) Yes it is the same. Thanks for +1, do You find this useful? :)

Comment: yes, I like that you show that you can also use Mathematicas "directory functions": `FileNameJoin`, `Directory`, `SetDirectory` and `NotebookDirectory`.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I think it is a good habit to use them if You have more than one table to import. It is so convenient and fast.

Comment: Thanks for all these comments. I have one follow up, related to this: NumberConcentration = Import[#, "Table"][[87]] & /@ files; I'm taking all the values in row 87 for all the files in "files." However, my data of interest, depending on the file, is in row 87 or 88. I'm not sure how to incorporate that into the code since I'm not really familiar with how the # and @/ operators work

Comment: @l3win what is in the rest of rows then, how can I help You if I do not know how it depends on the file? :) (take a look at `Select` etc. For example `Select[filedata, Length[#]==lengthofcollumn &]`)

Comment: I was trying something like this NumberConcentration = Import[#, "Table"][[{88,87,87,88,88,88,88,88}]] & /@ files; to make it put 88th row of file1 into column 1, 87th row of file2 into column 2, etc

Comment: @l3win Change [[87]] there: `Do[NumberConcentration[[;;, i]] = Import[files[[i]], "Table"][[87]], {i,Length@files}];` to `[[pos[[i]] ]]`, where `pos = {88,87...`

Comment: @l3win so it will look: 'pos={87,...}; Do[NumberConcentration[[;;, i]] = Import[files[[i]], "Table"][[pos[[i]]]], {i,Length@files}];`